# How exactly do I use a Metamagic Rod?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, magic-items

So the [section on Rods](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rods.htm) mentions with its activation that:

> **Activation**
>
> Details relating to rod use vary from item to item. See the individual descriptions for specifics.

The [Metamagic Rod section](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rods.htm#metamagicRods) says that:

> All the rods described here are use-activated (but casting spells in a threatened area still draws an attack of opportunity).

And finally the [section on Use-activated](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/magicItemBasics.htm#useActivated) reads (snipped the irrelevant parts):

> Use-Activated
>
> This type of item simply has to be used in order to activate it. A character has to drink a potion, swing a sword, interpose a shield to deflect a blow in combat, look through a lens, sprinkle dust, wear a ring, or don a hat. Use activation is generally straightforward and self-explanatory.
>
> Many use-activated items are objects that a character wears. Continually functioning items are practically always items that one wears. A few must simply be in the character’s possession (on his person). However, some items made for wearing must still be activated. Although this activation sometimes requires a command word, usually it means mentally willing the activation to happen. The description of an item states whether a command word is needed in such a case.

Now, the specific rods mention nothing about "must wave around" or "must have in hand" or anything. Many of the others do. This makes me think that a Metamagic Rod simply has to be on your person in order to work. But is this correct, or must I be holding it?

And if it has to be on my person, does stuffing it in extra-dimensional space on my body count? Ideally I want the rod to be in my Handy Haversack, because my Str 8 Halfling simply doesn't have the carrying capacity for the thing.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Description of each rod states:

> The **wielder** can cast...

Meanwhile, **to wield** means:

> to use (a weapon, instrument, etc.) effectively; handle or employ actively.

[More definitions, all pretty similar.](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/wield)

The *Magic Item Compendium* seems to clarify it even further. **Activating Magic Items** section (p. 219) includes this sentence:

> A **rod** or wand **must be held in your hand**

Also, each rod described in the compendium (including metamagic rods from sources other than DMG) has the following entry for "Body Slot":

> -- (held)

**For some softer arguments**

Take this sentence from the confusing "Use-activated" section in the SRD:

> Use activation is generally straightforward and self-explanatory.

Obviously it is not for rods, but it should. Substitute "rod" with "scepter" (because [*Rods are scepterlike devices*](http://www.d20srd.org/srd/magicItems/rods.htm)) and it may become more clear. "Using" a scepter is probably a bit more *self-explanatory* - imagine a king holding a scepter hidden under his cloak.

Comment: Also a good argument.

Answer (score 7):

MIC's wording, per burlap's answer, is very clear, and even the rod descriptions' inclusion of "the wielder" puts doubt on this answer. Original answer:

---

Reading a little further in the section on metamagic rods, we find this:

> **Possession** of a metamagic rod does not confer the associated feat on the owner, only **the ability to use** the given feat a specified number of times per day.

There it is in black and white: while possession *doesn't* actually give you the feat, it *does* let you use it.

Possession isn't very clearly defined anywhere, but it seems reasonable that, at the very least, any item *attended* by a character is in that character's possession*. That doesn't necessarily qualify a rod in a handy haversack by itself, but it's hard to imagine a case in which something entirely contained in an item you possess is not something you also possess.

<sub>**Possibly barring conflicting attending characters, or items that the character physically cannot move.*</sub>

Comment: Ah, I hadn't considered that part to refer to how the item was used, but that does make sense.

Comment: @Erik: For what it's worth, I don't think I'd play it this way; I'd just houserule that MM rods must be wielded. But I do think this is RAW and I do think it is playable.

Comment: Any owner can clearly use the rod: the question seems to be  about activating it without *using* in the sense of wielding.

Comment: @TimLymington: Yes, and that's precisely what this answer claims. You may disagree, I suppose, but the point is this: possession and casting a suitable spell in the proper manner is *all* that's needed (as far as I can tell) for MM rods to be activated.